# How do I merge a local branch into TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

I did a stupid thing and branched my project on my local disk instead of doing it on the TFS. So now I have two projects on my disk: the old one which has TFS bindings and the new, which doesn't. I want to merge those changes back into the TFS project. How would I go about doing that? I can't do Compare because my local branch has no TFS bindings. There should be some way to compare the differences between the two projects locally and then meld the differences into the old project and check-in, but I can't find an easy way of doing that. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a 3rd party tool to compare and merge.
You can always do a get on the source (c:\tfs\solution) and compare it with the local project (c:\myLocalSolution).
Check out the entire tfs solution for edit before merging your local to the tfs.